# What's the difference between strcpy and stpcpy?

Tags: c, string

While reading the man page for `strcpy`, I discovered the function `stpcpy` also exists. However, the only difference I could notice in the man page is:

```
char *
stpcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);

char *
strcpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
```

So, what does `restrict` means here?

Comment: @{Everyone}: As always I received a bunch of great answers and I'm unable to mark all of them correct. Deciding which will be marked is the hardest part in these questions. I try to consider what was covered in the question and in some cases their age; however many different answers provide important information on different topics at different levels. Thank you all, and sorry, but I can't do much more than upvoting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `restrict` tells the compiler that `s1` and `s2` point to different arrays and that there is no overlap in the pointed-to arrays.  In some cases this may allow the compiler to perform extra optimizations (i.e., it could possibly copy blocks of multiple characters without having to check for overlap).

Note also that the return value is different:  `stpcpy` returns a pointer to the `\0` that was copied into the destination buffer while `strcpy` returns a pointer to the beginning of the string (effectively it does a `return s1;`).

Comment: `stpcpy` **is** part of POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stpcpy.html

Comment: In fairness it was just added in POSIX 2008.

Answer (score 35):

The question you are asking in the title and the question about `restrict` are actually two different totally unrelated questions. The other answers have already provided you with some good links that will help you to learn more about `restrict`.

However, the main difference between these two functons in not really the `restrict` specifier. In fact, in C99 version of C language specification, `strcpy` also has `restrict` qualification on its parameters. What you see on your man page for `strcpy` is simply not updated to conform to C99.

The main difference (which you seem to have missed) is the return value of `stpcpy`. `stpcpy` returns the pointer to the terminating `\0` character of the target string. This immediately makes clear the purpose of `stpcpy` and the rationale behind its existence: this function is intended to be used as an intelligent replacement to `strcat` function in situations when you need to concatenate multiple sub-strings into one string. You see, `strcat` works pretty poorly in such application (I'd even say that `strcat` has no meaningful uses in real code). The problem with `strcat` is that it rescans the destination string every time you add something to it, thus doing lots of unnecessary work and basically generating more heat than light. For example, the following code suffers from that problem

```
const char *part1, *part2, *part3, *part4;
...
char buffer[size]; /* assume that `size` is calculated properly */

strcpy(buffer, part1);
strcat(buffer, part2);
strcat(buffer, part3);
strcat(buffer, part4);
```

This code can be reimplemented in a much more reasonable way by using `stpcpy`

```
stpcpy(stpcpy(stpcpy(stpcpy(buffer, part1), part2), part3), part4);
```

And if you don't like chained calls, you can use an intermediate pointer to store the return value of intermediate `stpcpy` calls

```
char *end = buffer;

end = stpcpy(end, part1);
end = stpcpy(end, part2);
end = stpcpy(end, part3);
end = stpcpy(end, part4);
```

Of course it is worth mentioning that `strcpy` and `strcat` are standard functions, while `stpcpy` is not.

Comment: It's a pity I can't give two answers the correct mark. So I end up simply upvoting yours and saying thank you for providing these great examples.

Comment: I think this is the actual answer to the question, at least the question in the title.

Comment: Worth adding that stpcpy is defined in POSIX since 2008 version.

Comment: "I'd even say that `strcat` has no meaningful uses in real code." The uniquely terrible design of `strcat` is what makes it the canonical example in [the Joel on Software blog post that introduced the term "Shlemiel the painter's algorithm" to the programming world](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Comment: Besides from your answer, I wonder how can I also get such a deep grasp of understanding of C functions? Like is there a book, because man page doesn't say what the function is actually doing in the background .

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia entry for `restrict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)

In short, `restrict` tells the compiler that the segments of memory pointed to by s1 and s2 do not overlap; this allows the code to perform less error checking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link Mark, it's impressive that I wasn't aware of that keyword.

Answer (score 4):

> The `stpcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by src (including the terminating `'\0'` character) to the array pointed to by dest.  The strings
>          may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.

This satisfies the requirements for `restrict`, even if it's not in the function signature. If C99 is present, it could be added.

> `stpcpy()` returns a pointer to the end of the string dest (that is, the address of the terminating null byte) rather than the beginning.

This enables you to concatenate many strings more easily, and more efficiently, as `src` can be "tacked" onto the pointer returned from the last `stpcpy()`. The naive implementation of the alternative, `strcat` has to locate the end of the `dest` string before it can commence copying.

Note the following:

> This function is not part of the C or POSIX.1 standards, and is not customary on Unix systems, but is not a  GNU  invention  either.   Perhaps  it
>          comes from MS-DOS.  Nowadays, it is also present on the BSDs.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer Matt. I was getting a bit confused with `stpcpy` not being part of C (or POSIX), as the man page I saw was showing no requirement apart from including string.h . But your tip on BSDs made it clear. I'm on a FreeBSD flavor popularly known as Mac OS X :P

Comment: @sidyll: Well you could do much worse than Mac OS X, so bravo :)

Answer (score 3):

The other difference is the return value. From the man page: "The strcpy() and strncpy() functions return s1.  The stpcpy() function returns a pointer to the terminating `\0' character of s1."

Answer (score 3):

strcpy returns s1 but stpcpy returns s1+strlen(s2).