# better way to concatenate multiple strings in c?

Tags: c

Is there a better way to concatenate multiple strings together in c other than having multiple calls to strcat() all in a row, like below?

```
char prefix[100] = "";
strcat(prefix, argv[0]);
strcat(prefix, ": ");
strcat(prefix, cmd_argv[0]);
strcat(prefix, ": ");
strcat(prefix, cmd_argv[1]);
perror(prefix);
```

Comment: This is a case of [Shlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Beware of Microsoft's `_snprintf` which doesn't guarantee null termination of the destination buffer.

Comment: I like how it's actually done in the question with strcat.

Comment: Was the question also on the best practice, instead of just technical approach? How to manage a workflow of decision => modification, multiple times on a large string? (performance and memory concern)

Answer (score 33):

```
sprintf(prefix,"%s: %s: %s",argv[0],cmd_argv[0],cmd_argv[1]);
```

Or `snprintf` to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: Definitely change it to `snprintf`. `sprintf` simply should not be used in modern code.

Comment: Or we could over load the + operator and make it similar to java.

Answer (score 19):

snprintf would be the best and easiest to use option, though it may not be "fast".  You didn't state what your criteria was.  Simplicity is definitely this, though:

```
snprintf(prefix, sizeof(prefix), "%s: %s: %s", argv[0], cmd_argv[0], cmd_argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use `sprintf()` like others have suggested, but this is for completeness:

If you have [`stpcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stpcpy.html), then you can do:

```
char prefix[100] = "";
stpcpy(stpcpy(stpcpy(sptcpy(stpcpy(prefix, argv[0]), ": "),
        cmd_argv[0]), ": "), cmd_argv[1]);
perror(prefix);
```

The convenience with `stpcpy()` is that it can be "chained", as above.  Also, since `stpcpy()` returns a pointer to the end of the resultant string, subsequent `stpcpy()` calls don't need to go through the old data again and again.  So, it is more efficient than multiple `strcat()`s and probably more efficient than `sprintf()`.  `stpcpy()` is POSIX:2008.

Answer (score 6):

I might take a rep hit for this, but what the heck. The worst thing that can happen is I'll learn something.

I don't really use C these days, and I don't typically use C-style strings in C++. But one idea I have is to write a modified strcpy() that returns the end of the string:

```
char* my_strcpy(char*dest, const char* src)
{
    while ((*dest = *src++))
        ++dest;
    return dest;
}
```

Now Shlemiel can bring his bucket along with him:

```
char prefix[100] = "";
char* bucket = my_strcpy(prefix, argv[0]);
bucket = my_strcpy(bucket, ": ");
bucket = my_strcpy(bucket, cmd_argv[0]);
bucket = my_strcpy(bucket, ": ");
bucket = my_strcpy(bucket, cmd_argv[1]);
perror(prefix);
```

I haven't tested this. Comments?

EDIT: Removed the unnecessary `my_strcat()` function. Also it turns out to be the same as `stpcpy()`, which is apparently part of POSIX as of 2008. See http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/stpcpy/.

Comment: `my_strcpy()` is known as `stpcpy()` in POSIX - and you don't need `my_strcat()`, since `my_strcpy()` would work just as well (since you already have a pointer to the end of the string).

Comment: @caf: I thought of the `my_strcat()` point after I posted, but I didn't know about `stpcpy()`. See, I did learn something!

Comment: @caf: Actually, it appears `stpcpy()` is not POSIX: "The stpcpy() function conforms to no standard." (from http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/stpcpy/)

Comment: @caf: After further review, it was recently added to POSIX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826773/whats-the-difference-between-strcpy-and-stpcpy/5826799#5826799. I guess the man pages haven't caught up yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to build a string from other strings (which your example suggests), then you can use snprintf.

```
char prefix[100] = "";
snprintf( prefix, sizeof(prefix), "%s: %s: %s", argv[0], cmd_argv[0], cmd_argv[1]);
```

If you're trying to do concatenation of an existing string, where you can't use the format approach, then you're probably stuck with multiple calls to strcat, although I'd strongly suggest that you might want to consider using **`strncat`** instead and checking to ensure you don't have buffer overruns.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a char[fixed_size] as posted, rather than a char*, you can use a single, creative macro to do it all at once with a cout-like ordering rather than the disjointed printf style format.  If you are working with embedded systems, this method will allow you to leave out the large printf family of functions like `snprintf()` (This keeps dietlibc from complaining too) and doesn't even require `malloc()` or any functions from `<string.h>`.

```
#include <unistd.h> //for write
//note: you should check if offset==sizeof(buf) after use
#define strcpyALL(buf, offset, ...) do{ \
    char *bp=(char*)(buf+offset); /*so we can add to the end of a string*/ \
    const char *s, \
    *a[] = { __VA_ARGS__,NULL}, \
    **ss=a; \
    while((s=*ss++)) \
         while((*s)&&(++offset<(int)sizeof(buf))) \
            *bp++=*s++; \
    if (offset!=sizeof(buf))*bp=0; \
}while(0)

char buf[100];
int len=0;
strcpyALL(buf,len, argv[0],": ", cmd_argv[0],": ",cmd_argv[1]);
if (len==sizeof(buf))write(2,"error\n",6);
else write(1,buf,len);
```

- Note 1, you can use any function that outputs a char*, including nonstandard functions like itoa() for converting integers to string types.
- Note 2, if you are using a shared library or are already using a printf style function anywhere in your statically built program, the only reason not to use snprintf() (since the compiled code would be larger with this method) would be that since it is inlined and doesn't call any external functions, so it should be relatively fast.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [snprintf](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html) function

```
char prefix[100];
snprintf(prefix, 100, "%s: %s: %s", argv[0], cmd_argv[0], cmd_argv[1]);
```

Comment: better not to use  %s  for  ":"  you can simply put the  :  instead of  %s

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a Macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define a argv[0]
#define b argv[1]
#define c argv[2]
#define strcat1(a,b,c) strcat(prefix, a);\
                       strcat(prefix, ": ");\
                       strcat(prefix, b);\
                       strcat(prefix, ": ");\
                       strcat(prefix, c);\
                       perror(prefix);\



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char prefix[100] = "";
    strcat1(a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```