# Too much code for string concatenation in C

Tags: c, string

I get a lot of strcat lines in my code. Is there a better way to concatenate strings in C?

```
char material[50]; // it is defined before this code.
char result[10000];
strcpy(result, "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\n");
strcat(result, "shadingNode -asShader lambert -n ");
strcat(result, material);
strcat(result, ";\n");
```

Comment: I don't think so. If you find yourself adding a lot of lines, it might be more useful for you reading a file.

Comment: Remember that C is really not too much more than a macro assembler; take comfort in having complete control over your code execution.

Comment: So the best way of concatenating strings in C is to use Ruby? Right.

Comment: @James: well, Ruby is implemented in C. So, in a way, yes :-)

Comment: If you're appending to big long strings with multiple strcat-s, you can run into performance issues.  Each strcat has to iterate to the end of the target string.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm

Comment: @sergei: Actually, this code doesn't "perform"!  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm (or http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html for the original).

Comment: I meant C in general, as "close to the metal" (but ugly) language. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [better way to concatenate multiple strings in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889880/better-way-to-concatenate-multiple-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 13):

You could use a format string in conjunction with [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) (safe compared to `sprintf()`):

```
snprintf(result, 10000,
    "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\nshadingNode -asShader lambert -n %s;\n",
    material);
```

Comment: To make it easier to read, I would split the format string into 2 lines (`"// Assign ... \n"` ↵ `"shadingNode ..."`)

Comment: why it is safer than sprintf() ? i woud have suggested sprintf that i use often...

Comment: @eharvest:  If there's not enough space in `result`, the data will try to write to memory the does not belong to the application, causing a segfault.

Answer (score 4):

`strcat` is only really suitable for really small strings; it has several problems for anything non-trivial, such as:

- Due to the [Schlemiel The Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) problem, `strcat` is O(n) over the length of the input strings, that is, the longer your strings, the longer each concatenation takes. This is because strcat has to walk the entire string to find its end. To solve this, store the length of the string along with the string data, which will allow you to jump directly to the end of the string.
- It does not do any bounds checking. If you `strcat` too much onto the end of a string, it will happily write past the end of the string, producing a segfault in the best case, a severe security vulnerability in the worst, and most likely some bugs that will make you bash your head against the wall. `strncat` partially solves this problem, as long as you pass it the correct size of the destination buffer.
- If your destination buffer is too small, neither `strcat` nor `strncat` will increase its size: you'll have to do this yourself.

There are two practical solutions in your situation:

a) The Tower Of Hanoi algorithm: Build a stack of strings. If a new string is shorter than the stack top, push it onto the stack. If it's longer, pop off the top, concatenate, and repeat the process with the result. When you're done pushing, concatenate what's on the stack. This is what `std::stringstream` in C++ or `StringBuilder` in .NET do, and if you look around, I'm sure you'll find a suitable implementation in C.

b) Write your strings directly to a stream. What you're outputting looks a lot like code - why not write it to a file directly?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
sprintf(result, "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\nshadingNode -asShader lambert -n %s;\n\0", material);
```

Comment: Good idea, but use `snprintf` instead. Safety first!

Comment: Be careful to not overflow 'result'.  Actually raw strcpy, strcat has the same problem.  (See @Jan's suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Try `stpcpy`; see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826819/318716). Your sample code becomes:

```
   char material[50]; // it is defined before this code.
   char result[10000], *p = result;
   p = stpcpy(p, "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\n");
   p = stpcpy(p, "shadingNode -asShader lambert -n ");
   p = stpcpy(p, material);
   p = stpcpy(p, ";\n");
```

This function is available in Linux; the `man` page for `stpcpy` on my system states:

> This function is not part of the C or POSIX.1 standards, and is not customary on Unix systems, but is not a GNU invention either. Perhaps it comes from MS-DOS.

If you don't have it, it is easy enough to write:

```
   char *stpcpy(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src) {
      return strcpy(dst, src) + strlen(src);
   }
```

This assumes you are aware of the dangers of [strcpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Criticism).

Comment: This is of course the same as cHoa's `faster_cat`, which I ignored on first reading. But Idelic's comment that `stpcpy` is `POSIX` seens to be incorrect.

Comment: `stpcpy` is in POSIX.1-2008, according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stpcpy.html. See also the updated man page at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stpcpy.3.html.

Comment: @Idelic: Thank you for the correction. I myself have just recently advanced from HPUX 10.20 (circa 1996) to CentOS 5 (circa 2007).  I might get to 2008 eventually :(

Answer (score 0):

C is mostly a do-it-yourself language.

Now that you know *how* to concat strings, you should write your own function to make it easier.

I'd suggest something like:

```
char*  str_multicat(char* result, ...);
```

And call it something like:

```
str_mutlicat(result, "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\n",
                     "shadingNode -asShader lambert -n ",
                     material,
                     ";\n",
                     NULL);
```

*(hint, if you don't know the `...` syntax, look into `va_arg`, `va_start`, `va_end`)*

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that returns a pointer to the end of the string, and use that end pointer in future calls.  That'd eliminate a bunch of the extra "first, find the end of the string" stuff.

```
char* faster_cat(char* dest, const char* src)
{
     strcpy(dest, src);
     return dest + strlen(src);
}
```

Use like:

```
char result[10000];
char *end = &result[0];
result[0] = '\0';  // not strictly necessary if you cat a string, but why not
end = faster_cat(end, "// Assign new material to worldGlobe\n");
end = faster_cat(end, "shadingNode -asShader lambert -n ");
end = faster_cat(end, material);
end = faster_cat(end, ";\n");

// result now contains the whole catted string
```

Comment: It'd probably be faster, too, since i did this in terms of standard C functions (and as a result, end up iterating over each chunk twice -- once with `strcpy` and once with `strlen`).  You can't count on POSIX functions being available outside of *nix, though.  MSVC's library doesn't seem to have `stpcpy`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It would by pretty straight forward to build a string buffer struct that will keep track of the current position in your buffer, and combine that with `vsprintf` to get a `catf()`.  The function `vsnprintf()` (assuming it's available) is just like `printf`, except it takes a `va_list` instead of `...` after the format string.

This approach has the advantage over other answers that it lets you 'cat' from anywhere in your code that has access to the struct without explicitly carrying around the current length or recalculating each time it like `strcat` does.

Here's a rough sketch free of charge.....

```
/* Note: the typedef is for the pointer, not the struct. */
typedef struct StrBufStruct { 
   char * buffer, 
   size_t size, 
   size_t pos 
} * StrBuf;

/* Create a new StrBuf. NOTE: Could statically allocate too. */
StrBuf newStrBuf(size_t size){
   StrBuf sb;
   sb = malloc( sizeof(struct StrBufStruct) );
   sb->size = size;
   sb->pos = 0;
   sb->buffer = malloc( size );
   /* TODO: ALWAYS CHECK YOUR MALLOC!!! */
}

int sbcatf( StrBuf b, char * fmt, ... )
{
   va_list ap;
   int res;
   if( b->pos < b->size )
   {  
      va_start(ap,fmt);
      res = vsnprintf( b->buffer[b->pos], b->size - b->pos, fmt, ap );
      b->pos += res;
      va_end();
   } else {
     /* If you want to get really fancy, use realloc so you don't have to worry 
       about buffer size at all.  But be careful, you can run out of memory. */
   }
}

/* TODO: Write a free/delete function */

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int i;
   /* initialize your structure */
   StrBuf sb = newStrBuf(10000);

   /* concatenate numbers 0-999 */
   for(i=0; i < 1000; i++){
      sbcatf(sb, "I=%d\n", i);
   }

   /* TODO: whatever needs to be done with sb->buffer */

   /* free your structure */
   deleteStrBuf(sb);
}
```

Also note that if all you're trying to do is make a really long string but want to be able to have line breaks in your code, this is usually acceptable, although I won't personally guarantee portability.  I also use the technique to separate strings at `"\n"` line breaks to make the code look like the resulting string really would.

```
const char * someString = "this is one really really really really"
    "long stttttttttrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrriiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnngggggg"
    " because the compiler will automatically concatenate string"
    " literals until we reach a ';' after a \" character";
```